# Some newbie questions about starting webOS emulator in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mobile, emulation, webos

I just followed the following link:
https://developer.palm.com/content/resources/develop/developing_with_the_eclipse_ide.html
to install webOS SDK, virtual box, Eclipse plugin etc.. and everything seems working fine. 
However, I do find some problems annoying and I dont know how to fix them:

1. the emulator always starts with the window size as 1024x768, which is too big and I can not find where to resize the window
2. I just clicked the "hello world App" in Eclipse and then run the app in emulator, the app seems working fine except the app had been rotated 90 degrees clockwise. I haven't done anything yet, but don't know how to fix the problem.

So far, not so pleasant user experiences with webOS development.

Comment: are you sure you want to invest time in webos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good questions.  One problem is that you're following examples for creating Mojo apps whereas the emulator you've installed is setup for Tablet development, which uses Enyo.  Try some of the examples in the Enyo framework directory or try following the Enyo tutorial from here: https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/enyo/tutorial.html

Also, if what you did want to do is do phone development then you'll want to take a look at the bottom of the SDK download page: https://developer.palm.com/content/resources/develop/sdk_pdk_download.html

Just download whichever image(s) you want and install it following the instructions found there.  When the emulator starts it will start in the size appropriate to the device being emulated.

For more information on the emulator itself, check this page:  https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/tools/emulator.html

And to answer the comment on your question, there are a lot of TouchPad tablets out there which HP has said it will continue to support.  Developers are reporting very good sales of apps.